# Connect to a remote desktop

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line, server, remote-control

I would like to remotely control a windows server from Linux Ubuntu. I am able to connect using the rdesktop command I was however wondering if there is a possibility to, for example, restart a service, or manually pull the server out of a pool, restart it and put it back simply using the command line.

If you know about any useful commands that would be great :) I am however simply trying to figure out if this is actually even possible as I am new to Linux...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You are basically asking about how to control Windows from the command line. If you are able to connect to the screen of a Windows PC and open a socalled "dosbox" you can issue any command you like (and your permissions grant to you)

Services can be controlled with the `sc` command, a restart can be used with the `shutdown` command. Besides that you can call many more functions, from the classic command line or even with Powershell.

But all of this is based on manual interaction.